# DBD::Oracle fails to connect with OCIEnvInit when called when accessed through webserver only

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi

I have a simple perl script that uses DBD::Oracle to run a query and print the results. It works fine from the command line, but I also have a PHP script that runs it and reads the output. When the PHP script is accessed through apache it fails to connect, with the error "OCIEnvInit".

I've tried creating a shell script that re-sets all the environment variables available in the shell but that didn't help, and I also tried setting the debugging output for DBI but got nothing. What could cause this error when the script does work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `ORACLE_HOME` and other relevant environment variables (e.g., `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) that are set in your shell when you run the script from the command line are also set to the same values in the apache/PHP process?

Comment: Strangely the command line doesn't have the values set but apache does. I will find out if removing them helps.

Comment: It turns out that removing them from the apache environment did work.